# Total amount of financing already provided to each customer

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have three separate tables:

```
SystemA_Cash
SystemA_Loans 
SystemB_CarLoans
```

Each table has `Cash_AdvanceID` field, `Customer`, & `Funded Amount`.

I need to total the amount funded for each customer.

Each customer can be present in any of the tables too.

So far I did

```
SELECT SystemA_CashAdvances.CashAdvanceID, SystemA_CashAdvances.Customer, 
SystemA_CashAdvances.Funded_Amount 
FROM 
SystemA_CashAdvances
INNER JOIN
SystemA_Loans ON SystemA_Loans.CashAdvanceID = SystemA_CashAdvances.Cash_AdvanceID
INNER JOIN
SytemB_CarLoans ON SystemA_CashAdvances.Cash_AdvanceID = SystemB_CarLoans.CashAdvanceID;
```

It doesn't seem to return one table with the customers and the total amount each was funded.

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL and MS Access are very different.  Tag your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you need `CashAdvanceID` in the result for, and if you need it, what do you want to do with it? I suppose it can have different values in the three tables, even for the same customer. Should this not be left out?

Comment: Hey Gordon I'm using ms-access and the sql in it

Comment: Trincot. Cash_AdvanceID is the primary key within all three tables.

Comment: So you don't need to see Cash_AdvanceID in the final output?

Comment: Not necessarily but it could be preferable since each Cash_AdvanceID is tied to one customer within each of the three tables.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` and `GROUP BY` for this, like:

```
SELECT  Cash_AdvanceID,
        Customer, 
        SUM(Funded_Amount) AS "Total_Funded_Amount"
FROM (
        SELECT  Cash_AdvanceID,
                Customer, 
                Funded_Amount 
        FROM    SystemA_CashAdvances
        UNION
        SELECT  Cash_AdvanceID,
                Customer, 
                Funded_Amount 
        FROM    SystemA_Loans
        UNION
        SELECT  Cash_AdvanceID,
                Customer, 
                Funded_Amount 
        FROM    SytemB_CarLoans
)
GROUP BY Cash_AdvanceID,
         Customer;
```

To do this with `JOIN` will be hard, as MS Access does not support a full outer join, as other database engines do. The closest is a one-sided outer join, as follows:

```
SELECT    a.Cash_AdvanceID,
          a.Customer, 
          a.Funded_Amount + Nz(l.Funded_Amount)
                          + Nz(c.Funded_Amount) AS "Total_Funded_Amount" 
FROM      (SystemA_CashAdvances AS a
LEFT JOIN SystemA_Loans AS l
       ON a.Cash_AdvanceID = l.Cash_AdvanceID)
LEFT JOIN SytemB_CarLoans AS c
       ON a.Cash_AdvanceID = c.Cash_AdvanceID;
```

The above will work for customers that appear at least in the table *SystemA_CashAdvances*. If they only appear in another table, they will be excluded from the result. To get those in as well, you would need to use `UNION` again, which brings us back to the first solution above.

Comment: Hey so this worked but it gave me two columns one with the customer but its numbered instead of names and the total_funded amount.

Comment: The final output would preferable be in 3 columns. ID, Customer, Total funded amount. The second field has the customer name the first has the cash_advanceID.

Comment: Updated the answer with 3 columns. You still did not say where the customer name is stored.

Comment: Much appreciated! Within each of the three tables you get 3 columns 1) Cash_AdvanceID 2) Customer (customer names) 3) Funded Amount. Each customer can be in any of the tables. Once or twice since its for different types of funds

Comment: So i think in this case maybe Inner Join will be better than Union

Comment: Something like inner join systemA_Loans on systemA_Loans.customer = SystemA_CashAdvances.customer

Comment: If my answer is not what you need, then I don't understand what you are asking. Could you please add to your question some example data (in all three tables), and the desired output? That would make it all clear.

Comment: No I think your answer solves the problem my only idea was that what would happen if you swapped union with join.

Comment: Yes you are right and as I stated some customers do appear in all three tables but with different amount of funding. Therefore I was thinking there must be a way to integrate normal inner join within access perhaps using double parentheses.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying: if you use `innner join` you will not have the amounts for customers that only appear in 1 or 2 of the tables. I suppose you would need those also. So then `inner join` is **not** a solution for you. Double parentheses will not help in that context.

Comment: Yes okay it makes sense :) So do you have an idea about what should be done if the customer does appear in more than one table?

Comment: I added this to my answer, including the limitations of such a solution.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: One last point. The aliases such as a.cash_advanceID aren't recognized by the system. Plus access doesn't accept more than one query at a time. It really is an obsolete system.

Comment: Ah yes, in MSAccess you need to put the aliases in double quotes, I think, and the joins in brackets. I will update the answer. Let me know if that was it.